# How to check for references to other assemblies in the project in visual studio from my own assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-assembly

This is an area of program development that I am definitely new to and consequently I'll apologise in advance if I have used the incorrect nomenclature in phrasing my question.

Basically I have devised an assembly (dll) which has been designed to add some additional functionality to a third parties controls suite.  In order for my assembly to work and provide that additional functionality those third party assemblies to which this functionality applies need to be present in the developers project.  In all likelihood they probably will be already (after why would they want to add my assembly if they weren't?) however all of the required ones may not yet be present.

Is there a way (from within my own assembly) to be able to check the references in the project to which it has been added for the other third party assemblies that should be there and then either prompt the developer to add them, or automatically add them.

I'll be doing this in vb, but can convert c# (with the obvious proviso that it's not using something that simply isn't available in vb).

Thanks

Comment: Are those third party assemblies freely distributable? If that's the case, you should probably create a nuget package.

Comment: No they are not.  They form part of a controls suite that the end user that I am targeting with my assembly would most likely have already purchased. Freely distributing via NuGet would not I believe prove to be acceptable behaviour from the third party's point of view!

Comment: You can still make a nuget package (not including third party assemblies) and use the corresponding install.ps1 PowerShell script to check / define the required assembly references.